# cmd.Executenonquery() Completes but doesnt work

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012

I am currently trying to get my code to insert data into my database.

I have the following code.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCommit.Click
        Dim Con As SqlConnection
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim connstring As String
        connstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Assignment.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
        Try
            Con = New SqlConnection(connstring)

            cmd = New SqlCommand("Insert into Rota ([Id],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday],[Sunday],[UserID]) Values('" & chosen & "','" & mon & "','" & tues & "','" & wed & "','" & thur & "','" & fri & "','" & sat & "','" & sun & "','" & user & "')", Con)
            cmd.Connection.Open()
            Dim rows As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox(rows.ToString() & " rows affected")
            MsgBox("done")

            cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * from Rota", Con)
            Dim rows2 As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox(rows2.ToString() & " rows affected")
        Catch ex As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
```

When My code executes, it comes back and tells me that the row has been affected. However if I view the actual database. it has not inserted it!

Comment: Use a try catch block and read the exception.

Comment: Done that, and returns no errors!

Comment: Any particular reason why you are executing your query twice?

Comment: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets5p4.html

Comment: Removed the double execute, and added the catch exeception. The only message box to show is "Done"

Comment: HEH????   there is 9 columns, and 9 variables????

Comment: Are you sure it has not been inserted?

Comment: Yes. When i view the database afterwards, the file size has not changed, the show data, displays nothing. Therefore I'm fairly certain its not.

Comment: DO a SELECT * FROM rota to be sure.

Comment: I have updated the initial post with the extra code. When i use the SELECT *, it says -1 rows

Comment: `SELECT *` returns a result set, not a record count, so `ExecuteNonQuery` won't give a meaningful result.

Comment: Ok, but I also tried it in the query builder, and returned the result 0.

Comment: Bit of a shot in the dark, but the connection timeout of 30 and the fact that you are not closing/disposing of the connection after you are done, may have an impact.  Try closing the connection and then check the DB.  Maybe it thinks that it is failing?

Comment: Also try and change "Insert into Rota ([" to "Insert into dbo.Rota ([".  It could be a user schema issue.

Comment: @Anthony Horne Niether made any difference. :(

Comment: Sorry to say, but I did a test and it worked on my side.  created table with all cols as varchar(10) AND IT worked - even for a attachDB SQL.  Sorry I can't offer any more suggestions.  Are you sure you are looking at the correct instance of this database?

Comment: @Anthony Horne I do beleive so :(   I dont know if this is allowed via here, but If you email me at malloyj@btinternet.com I will send you my code, to allow you to "tinker", and see if you can get it working!

Comment: @TheBlueDog Do you know if stack overflow caters for uploads of complete projects for questions?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne: No, it doesn't, you'd have to use Dropbox or something silmilar; whether or not anyone would download it to look at though is another matter... ;)

Comment: @AnthonyHorne:[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/k7r8nmrjrqf0mio/groupsoftwareproject.zip)

Comment: @user3343446 I was able to replicate the issue.  I was able to get around it by adding a single record to the table AND add a primary key (identity col).  There is some mention on MSDN that the command builder does not work well without a primary key, but who knows.  It is now able to insert through your application.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne: That must be an MSSQL thing, I've never had that issue with a MySQL database.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Me too. Colour me stumped - but it will work for the user. I work with both MySQL (redmine, etc.) and mssql (much more).

Comment: @AnthonyHorne: Microsoft - 'nuff said.

Comment: @TheBlueDog You said it.  Struggling my "donkey" off trying to get VS2013 <> EF <> Odata working.  Prerelease + prerelease +....

Comment: @AnthonyHorne I have added the primary key, and also added a dummy row. Still is not working!

Comment: I did attach it to a SQL engine (through SSMS) and added a record there - using a script you provided.  Then afterwards, while it was attached, it was adding records successfully.

Comment: The only place I have to add records manually, is via the designer within visual studio 2012. Does ti work for you, if you do not run it through the SSMS?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne    Still having this issue. Hopefully an easy fix though. As you say, it works for you!

Comment: I open the SMSS (SQL Express 2012) and attach the database (from your folder).  Then added a few records (using the script you provided) and then after that, you app seemed to add as expected.  I did, as a test, also add a datareader to see what was coming back, but removed it after the test, i.e. the SQL Script said "INSERT........; SELECT @@IDENTITY".

Answer (score 0):

First of all your checking by below code is wrong:

```
    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * from Rota", Con)
    Dim rows2 As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

for `select` statements you should use `ExecuteReader()` or change it to `Select count(*) as cn from ROTA` and run it via `ExecuteScalar()`

Second you need to run `Sql Profiler` and set a break point right after your first `ExecuteNonQuery()` and then see the `Profiler` to be sure that your command is correct and is inserted correctly, then without going further, in `SQL Mamagenent Studio` run `SELECT * from Rota with(nolock)` and be sure that data is inserted. Then continue running your application. Then run this query `SELECT * from Rota`. If in the last query data is not there but was in the first query you have `transaction rollback` problem, but if there the record wasn't in both of them you have insert problem and if the record exists in both, your application for querying is not working well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I do not have SQL profiler, however I did change it so that is it now `ExecuteReader()`. The result is still 0

Comment: @RezaRahmati I think the problem is more related to the preceding insert and not so much on the SELECT.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne Yes, The second part of my answer is focusing on this.

Comment: @RezaRahmati Apologies, I did not finish reading your answer.